# Increase hydra brute force login attempts

Tags: brute-force

I have recently came to know about hydra and i am playing with it using brute force. The number of login attempts are almost 10 attempts / second, I am trying with my password, so if my password strength is 8 characters (just a-z,A-Z,0-9) it will take days. How can i optimize the login attempts or increase the number of attempts / sec. I have ci7 hp laptop.

Answer (score 1):

(AFAIK) There is not an explicit "tries per second" config option in HYDRA, normally you can define the number of tasks that will be involved in the attack. I have checked the default option and it is 16 (in the command line utility), so I believe that the service you are trying to test against might have a big latency or some kind of delay before answering wrong attempts. Anyway you could try to tune it by increasing the number of tasks with the option "-t".

The latter is not an uncommon solution so you can expect that, also, you should consider that many services will temporary blacklist your IP if you try to log-in more than "n" times (being "n" an small number of tries like 5 or 10).

[Here you have an Hydra manual for both command line and GUI utility.](http://www.aldeid.com/wiki/Thc-hydra)